# Equivalent wstring operation?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to do the same operation, but with a compatible code for visual c++ 2010:

```
wstring widen(string Str) {
    const size_t wcharCount = Str.size() + 1;
    vector<wchar_t> Buffer(wcharCount);

    return wstring{
        Buffer.data(),(size_t)MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), -1, Buffer.data(), (int)wcharCount);
    };
}
```

Specifically this:

```
return wstring{
    Buffer.data(),(size_t)MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), -1, Buffer.data(), (int)wcharCount);
};
```

How do i return a wstring, but with another way... because i'm getting errors, because the compiler i must use is older.

I also want to learn more about converting the code, compatible with older versions of Microsoft visual c++ (this case here, i want to compile this in 2010 version (and i have it)).

EDIT:
As an useful to track errors:

|Line 5| error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'|

|Line 5| error C2275: 'std::wstring' : illegal use of this type as an expression|

Comment: When asking a question because you're "getting errors", it's very helpful to show, you know, exactly what the errors are.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, just throw the error message at a web search. BTW: A 2010 compiler is unlikely to support C++11 syntax, which may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: VS 2010 is not a C++ 11 compliant compiler.  Whatever C++11 "features" it has, they were implemented prior to the official launch of C++ 11, thus are iffy to use (IMO).  Why such an old compiler?

Comment: Well, because i want to compile it in code::blocks, and i don't found any info for compiling in code::blocks with C++ major than C++ 10 (2010).

Comment: Codeblocks is not a C++ compiler.  It is an IDE that runs a compiler.  You need to know the brand and version of the actual C++ compiler that is being used.  Also, why not use the super-simple Visual Studio 2019 IDE?  It is free (the community edition), and can run the latest version of Visual C++ with no issues.

Comment: Oh sure, it's correct, is only a IDE :D . Also, gonna try the visual studio 2019 community edition

Answer (score 1):

For older (pre-C++11) compilers, use parenthesis (`return wstring(...)`) instead of braces (`return wstring{...}`), and also use `std::vector::operator[]` to access the allocated array, not `std::vector::data()` (which didn’t exist yet), eg:

```cpp
return wstring(
    &Buffer[0], MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), -1, &Buffer[0], wcharCount)
);
```

That being said, the source `std::string`’s size is the wrong size to use for the `std::vector`. Call `MultiByteToWideChar()` twice - call it once with a NULL output buffer to calculate the necessary size, and then call it again to write to the buffer.  And, you should be using the `std::string`’s actual size instead of -1 for the source buffer size.

```cpp
wstring widen(const string &Str) {
    const int wcharCount = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), Str.size(), NULL, 0);
    vector<wchar_t> Buffer(wcharCount);
    return wstring(
        &Buffer[0], MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), Str.size(), &Buffer[0], wcharCount)
    );
}
```

Note that in C++11 and later, it is safe to use a pre-sized `std::wstring` directly as the destination buffer, you don’t need the `std::vector` at all, because `std::wstring` is *guaranteed* to use a single contiguous block of memory for its character data. And even in earlier compilers, this is *usually* safe in practice (though NOT *guaranteed*) because most implementations use a contiguous block anyway for efficiency:

```cpp
wstring widen(const string &Str) {
    const int wcharCount = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), Str.size(), NULL, 0);
    wstring Buffer;
    if (wcharCount > 0) {
        Buffer.resize(wcharCount);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, Str.c_str(), Str.size(), &Buffer[0]/* or Buffer.data() in C++17 */, wcharCount);
    }
    return Buffer;
}
```